# form_forでf.text_fieldに入力した値が空になる

Tags: ruby-on-rails

actions/new.html.slim.rb

```
= form_for(@action, :url => user_action_path) do |f|
  = f.text_field :one
  = f.text_field :two
  = f.text_field :three
  = f.submit
```

controllers/actions_controller.rb

```
def new
  @action = Action.new
end

def create
  @action = Action.new(params_action)
  if @action.save
    redirect_to room_path
  end
end

def params_action
  params.require(:action).permit(:one, :two, :three).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

エラー文
`undefined method 'permit' for "action":String`

```
request parameter
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OPUlMPtPZnDzl+lnT0zrOkf/+EuQwv9MsqT/5BDCgWfuq1uPdA0pS8QhFGtUsJzX0yKlHtbilHDPWT/iSeErIg==", "action"=>"create", "commit"=>"Create Action", "controller"=>"actions", "user_id"=>"1"}
```

text_fieldに値を入れても値が空になって飛んできます。。
このようなエラーは初めてで困惑しています。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`params[:action]`はRailsが利用するので別の名前にする必要があります。
`:action` 以外の名前を利用するように`form_for`に`:as`のオプションを設定してください。

actions/new.html.slim.rb

```
<%= form_for(@action, url: user_action_path, as: :act) do |f| %>
```

また、コントローラーの`params_action`メソッドの内容を以下のように変更することで動くと思います。

controllers/actions_controller.rb

```
def params_action
  params.require(:act).permit(:one, :two, :three).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
助かりました